# How to pass custom variables to BillingBlock.tpl?

Tags: extension, payment-processor

I found that the `BillingBlock.tpl` is included in `Main.tpl` file and all the variables are assigned to this templates using `Main.php` file. I can hardcode the variable there but I am worried about if there is another core update. So I am trying to override the `Main.php` file from my custom extension but it's not happening.

My question is how do I override the `Main.php` file in civicrm from custom extension ( custom payment processor ) or if there is other method built in civicrm with which I can pass variable to `Main.tpl` or `BillingBlock.tpl`.

P.S. I followed the same directory structure as of core.

```
customextension
├── CRM
   └── Contribute
       └── Form
           └── Contribution
               └── Main.php
```

Answer (score 1):

To Override Main.tpl file - you can try using Main.extra.tpl which should work

But Please try using - custom File - because if you are overriding the same file in some other extension it might not work sometime

```
function hook_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
$templatePath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)."/templates");
CRM_Core_Region::instance('billing-block')->add(array(
    'template' => "{$templatePath}/custom/custom.tpl",
));
}
```

and add your coding in the custom.tpl

Also please note that for billing address all the fields are hard coded in the core also same for validation -

If you need more help please let me know - thanks